# Is it possible to find when google bot is crawling any urls on my site and record the last access time to a text file on server

Tags: php, googlebot

Here's a code below which sends an email whenver any page is crawled by google and its resulting in spamming of mailbox. so is it possible to just record last crawled timestamp in a text file on server, which i can read later anytime using perl LWP mod.
file should have just this data: 29,jan 2012 GMT etc
If bot is visiting my site multiple times then it should overwrite txt file and record the last visit time only, please help with some implementation if possible

```
<?php
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot' ) !== false )
{
// paste your email address here
$my_email = 'your_email_address@email.com';
// notify via email
mail($my_email,'[Notification]Googlebot Visit', 'Googlebot has just visited your      website WEBSITE_NAME: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>
```

I think we can do it by checking if google bot is hitting the server and what time it requested any page of site from server?

Comment: You know how to detect the Googlebot... is your question on how to write text to a file?

Comment: yes, and how to detect what time it accessed server(timestamp) and overwrite txt file on server with latest crawled time

Comment: First, you have to make a distinction between real and fake Googlebot user agents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot' ) !== false ) {
    file_put_contents('somefile.txt', 'Googlebot was here - ' . date(DATE_RFC822));
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks Brad and sdlei, so will this function will overwrite and update any existing something.txt file during each visit by googlebot

Comment: No, it will overwrite and update `somefile.txt` relative to the path of the script.