# How to redirect indexation bots to a different route using a Vue.js SPA to server rendered pages for them to be crawled and indexed?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, seo, single-page-application

I need to develop a Vue.js SPA where some of its pages need to be referenced by search engines.

I've read about multiple ways to make SPAs SEO-Friendly so I found the following solutions

- Server-rendered pages
- Prerendering

Since we have a lot of dynamic content to index, generating a static page for each "row" in the database seems not acceptable since we have hundreds if not thousands of content pages.

- Creating multiple routes (one for users to visualize and one for bots to crawl)

This solution has been proposed by my manager and it interests me since it's more suitable for our case.

[I found this article that illustrates the idea using another SPA framework](https://www.journaldunet.fr/web-tech/tutoriels-seo/1203209-ajax-optimiser-le-referencement-et-le-crawl-d-une-application-web-monopage/)

My question here is how can I detect that a crawler or an indexation bot have accessed our SPA in order to redirect it to our server rendered web pages and how to actually achieve that in Vue.js 2 (Webpack) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about SEO, the solution is to use SSR. Read through https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#The-Complete-SSR-Guide.

If you already have server rendered webpages, as you mentioend in your question, then using SSR would be less work than keeping the Vue SPA and server app in sync. Not to mention, if the Vue SPA and server app show different content, this could hurt SEO and frustrate users.

Any method you use to target web crawlers can be by-passed, so there is no generic solution for this. Instead, try and focus on specific web crawlers, like Google's.

For Google, start by registering your app at https://www.google.com/webmasters. If you need to determine if the Google crawler visited your server, look at the user agent string; there are already other answers for that: [Is it possible to find when google bot is crawling any urls on my site and record the last access time to a text file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048531/is-it-possible-to-find-when-google-bot-is-crawling-any-urls-on-my-site-and-recor), https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en.